# Regular Expression to match a set of strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for the set of Strings as below. I've tried few of the online tools but unable to come up with tools

```
History_D , 
History_D-1,
History_D+1 ,
History_D+2 ,
```

What I have tried :

```
^History_D(\[-\+\][12])?$
```

and

```
/^History_D([+-]?[12])?$/
```

But none of them seem to work. Any pointers will be appreciated.
Note: I need a regex that could possibly match one of the above set of strings.

Comment: Your 1st example works just fine. Remember to set the multiline flag, when you want to match full lines (as indicated by the `^` and `$`). Working example: https://regex101.com/r/4EfHTf/1

Comment: You should only use "online tools" for reference, but test your patterns in the real target environment. The question is off-topic as your regexes work. Or it is unclear since it is not clear if the commas with whitespaces are present in the strings you test, or this is just formatting issue here.

Answer (score 0):

`/^History_D(\-|\+)*\d*\s*\,*$/gm` appears to work fine with Global and Multiline flags.

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com/3ftv2